# Nightwatch.js execute scenarios with specific tags

Tags: nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

I'm trying run some specific scenarios using tags but I'm unable to finsh some documentation regarding that. What I want to do is run all scenarios that are marked with a specific tag. Look at the example provided on the github but it doesn't say much. What I want to do is:

```
   @onlyone
  Scenario: a random feature
    Given: something
    When: I do something
    Then only this test should be ran
```

So what I want to do is run the following command `nightwatch --tag @onlyone` only the scenarios with that tag should be ran.

Answer (score 0):

Found the appropiate documentation, [Nightwatch Documentation](http://mucsi96.github.io/nightwatch-cucumber/) it was an error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it has been enough to run it from the command line without previous configuration.

Try this:

```
npm run test -- --tags @my-tag
```

or

```
npm run test:run -- --tags @my-tag
```

Hope this will work for you!